# show item of nested json array in template angular 5

Tags: json, angular, angular5

how can i show "comment" of this json data in my template ???

(this json comes from ngFor data)

```
{
  "product_id": 2,
  "author": 1,
  "category": 2,
  "title": "python",
  "description": "python desc",
  "filepath": null,
  "price": "50000",
  "created_date": "2018-01-28T03:30:00+03:30",
  "updated_date": "2018-01-28T03:30:00+03:30",
  "product_ratings": {
    "p_id": 2,
    "commenter": 1,
    "comment": "very nice totorial",
    "rating": 5,
    "created_date": "2018-02-05T03:30:00+03:30"
  }
}
```

i did like below

my component.html

```
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of products">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
      <img class="activator" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-200-200-7.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div>{{ data.title }}</div>
      <div>{{ data.description }}</div>
      <div *ngFor="let rate of data.product_ratings">{{ rate.comment }}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

but i get this error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

when i trying to access comment with :

```
{{ data.product_ratings.comment }}
```

i will get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of null
```

in browser console

Comment: is `products` an array or an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a `ngFor` loop in the object properties.

Instead of this line

```
<div *ngFor="let rate of data.product_ratings">{{ rate.comment }}</div>
```

You can do like this

```
<div>{{ data.product_ratings.comment }}</div>
```

NgFor only loops through arrays, you have got an object so you can access its properties using the simple dot syntax.

So you just need to check the product rating available before you bind it. You only getting this because sometimes you don't have data in your `ratings`

Like this

```
<div *ngIf="data.prodduct_ratings">{{ data.product_ratings.comment }}</div>
```

If you had an array of `product_rating` then this syntax would be helpful.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your `product_ratings` is just an object, not array. You can use simple property access to it instead of `*ngFor`

```
<div>{{ data.product_ratings?.comment }}</div>
```

Comment: when i do that i see 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of null

in browser console

Comment: Add `?` operator after the `product_ratings`.Means not all data have those properties

Answer (score 1):

As `data.product_ratings` is not array but just a `json` , so that is not Iterables , coz of that you are getting that error.

So you need to remove :

```
*ngFor="let rate of data.product_ratings"
```

and change

`{{ rate.comment }}` to `{{ data.product_ratings.comment }}`

Comment: when i do that i see 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment' of null

in browser console

Comment: I think comment is not in all of your data , try to do `{{ data.product_ratings?.comment }}`